# Doubt on a Lipschitz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

I am following [this](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) paper. Towards the top of page 23 the author has:
$$|D(v,t) - D(v_i,t)| \leq \frac{f(a+tv) - f(a+tv_i)}{t}| + |(v-v_i)\cdot \nabla f(a)| \leq C \cdot |v - v_t|$$

where $D$ denotes the total deriative in the direction of $v$ and $C$ comes from the Lipschitz constant. However, how does the $t$ in the denominator vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is Lipschitz: $$\left|\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a+tv_i)}{t}\right| = \left|\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a+tv_i)}{(a+tv)-(a+tv_i)}(v-v_i)\right|\le L|(v-v_i)|$$
where $L \ge 0$ is the Lipschitz constant.

He then puts $C = L +|\nabla f(a)|$, using Cauchy-Schwarz. Hope it is clear.